# SQLite: Update one column based on a condition set in another table

Tags: sql, sqlite, multiplication

I'm a total noob in SQL and I've only just begun working with SQLite, and this is my first post here, so please pardon my inherent lack of understanding. I've been self-teaching myself after graduating with a BA, so please bear with me lol.

I've managed to get the following query to work, but only if all of the data was a part of the same table. I've since broken my two tables into three separate tables: widgetCustomer, widgetSale, and widgetOrderInfo.

```
    UPDATE widgetOrderInfo
    SET extendedcost = (cost * qty) * (0.80) 
    WHERE widgetCustomer.IsASenior = 'Y';
            -- Seniors get a 20 percent discount;
```

^^ This is the part I'm having trouble with. Whenever I use this query SQLite returns, "No such column: IsASenior."

--NOTE: IsASenior is a column in widgetCustomer set to either 'Y' or 'N' based on a trigger earlier on in the code. I've gotten base multiplication to work very easily using only the data in the widgetOrderInfo table using the following query:

```
    UPDATE widgetOrderInfo 
    SET extendedcost = (cost * qty);
```

Very basic, I'm aware, but I'm unsure what I must do in order to get my widgetOrderInfo table to acknowledge the data in widgetCustomer's 'IsASenior' column.

Do I have to use a JOIN in order to access data between two tables in an UPDATE statement?

Any assistance would be great! Thanks!

---

FULL LIST AND ORDER OF QUERIES I'M CURRENTLY PERFORMING (Lots of place-holders; WIP)

---

```
CREATE TABLE widgetCustomer 
    ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, age INT, IsASenior TEXT, last_order_id INT, soItemID INT );
CREATE TABLE widgetSale 
    ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, item_id INT, item_name TEXT, customer_id INT, quan INT, price MONEY(8,2) );
CREATE TABLE widgetOrderInfo
    ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, salesOrderID INT, cost MONEY(8,2), qty INT, extendedcost MONEY(8,2) )
```

;

```
CREATE TRIGGER SeniorCheck AFTER INSERT ON widgetCustomer
    BEGIN
        UPDATE widgetCustomer 
        SET IsASenior = 'Y' WHERE age >= 65;
        UPDATE widgetCustomer 
        SET IsASenior = 'N' WHERE age < 65;
    END
```

;

```
INSERT INTO widgetCustomer (name, age, soItemID) 
    VALUES ('Ian', 24, 3);
INSERT INTO widgetCustomer (name, age, soItemID) 
    VALUES ('Andrew', 29, 2);
INSERT INTO widgetCustomer (name, age, soItemID) 
    VALUES ('John', 65, 1);
INSERT INTO widgetCustomer (name, age, soItemID) 
    VALUES ('Kathy', 60, 4)
```

;

```
CREATE TRIGGER newWidgetSale AFTER INSERT ON widgetSale
    BEGIN
        UPDATE widgetCustomer 
        SET last_order_id = NEW.id 
        WHERE widgetCustomer.id = NEW.customer_id;
    END
```

;

```
INSERT INTO widgetSale (item_id, item_name, customer_id, quan, price) 
    VALUES (1, 'Blue Brick', 3, 50, 9.95);
INSERT INTO widgetSale (item_id, item_name, customer_id, quan, price) 
    VALUES (2, 'Red Brick', 2, 30, 4.95);
INSERT INTO widgetSale (item_id, item_name, customer_id, quan, price) 
    VALUES (3, 'Black Brick', 1, 24, 9.95);
INSERT INTO widgetSale (item_id, item_name, customer_id, quan, price) 
    VALUES (4, 'Yellow Brick', 4, 30, 9.95)
```

;

```
CREATE TRIGGER SubtractQuan AFTER INSERT ON widgetOrderInfo FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        UPDATE widgetSale
        SET quan = (quan - New.qty)
        WHERE customer_id = New.id;
    END
```

;

```
INSERT INTO widgetOrderInfo (salesOrderID, cost, qty) 
        VALUES (283001, 9.95, 4);
INSERT INTO widgetOrderInfo (salesOrderID, cost, qty) 
        VALUES (283002, 4.95, 8);
INSERT INTO widgetOrderInfo (salesOrderID, cost, qty) 
        VALUES (283003, 9.95, 5);
INSERT INTO widgetOrderInfo (salesOrderID, cost, qty) 
        VALUES (283004, 9.95, 15)
```

;

```
    UPDATE widgetOrderInfo 
    SET extendedcost = (cost * qty)
```

;

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN qty BETWEEN 5 and 7 THEN 'parcel'
        WHEN qty BETWEEN 8 and 14 THEN 'package'
        WHEN qty BETWEEN 15  and 30 THEN 'box'
        WHEN qty BETWEEN 31 and 99 THEN 'crate'
    ELSE 'individually wrapped'
END
    AS PackagingBasedOnPurchaseSize,
    COUNT(*) qty FROM widgetOrderInfo
    GROUP BY 
    CASE
        WHEN qty BETWEEN 5 and 7 THEN 'parcel'
        WHEN qty BETWEEN 8 and 14 THEN 'package'
        WHEN qty BETWEEN 15  and 30 THEN 'box'
        WHEN qty BETWEEN 31 and 99 THEN 'crate'
    ELSE 'individually wrapped'
END
```

;

```
    SELECT * FROM widgetSale;
    SELECT * FROM widgetCustomer;
    SELECT * FROM widgetOrderInfo;
```

---

I can provide a link to my whole database if need be.

---

Comment: You must join `widgetOrderInfo` to `widgetCustomer`. Please provide the table schema so we can easily help you.

Comment: You should add some foreign keys to describe relations between your tables. the UPDATE will be easier to write.

Answer (score 3):

In an UPDATE statement, you can directly access only the updated table itself.
To access other tables, you need a subquery.

To find order info rows associated with senior customers, you can either look up the corresponding customer row for each order info row with a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE widgetOrderInfo
SET extendedcost = (cost * qty) * (0.80)
WHERE (SELECT IsASenior
       FROM widgetCustomer
       JOIN widgetSale ON widgetCustomer.id = widgetSale.customer_id
       WHERE widgetSale.id = widgetOrderInfo.salesOrderID
      ) = 'Y';
```

Or get all senior customers first, and check which order infos are in that set:

```
UPDATE widgetOrderInfo
SET extendedcost = (cost * qty) * (0.80)
WHERE salesOrderID IN (SELECT widgetSale.id
                       FROM widgetCustomer
                       JOIN widgetSale ON widgetCustomer.id = widgetSale.customer_id
                       WHERE IsASenior = 'Y');
```